# Vaadin no plugin found for prefix jetty

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, vaadin

Good evening, im trying to install vaadin framework and integrate it into my eclipse but everytime i try to run the maven build i keep getting this error block, the main part is that the prefix jetty is not recognized and im not sre how to deal with that. Please help

```
  [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [WARNING] The project com.gmail.khaled:my-starter-project:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT uses prerequisites which is only intended for maven-plugin projects but not for non maven-plugin projects. For such purposes you should use the maven-enforcer-plugin. See https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireMavenVersion.html
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] My Starter Project                                                 [pom]
[INFO] My Starter Project-backend                                         [jar]
[INFO] My Starter Project-ui                                              [war]
[INFO] Downloading from : https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading from : https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading from : https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading from : https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded from : https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (14 kB at 13 kB/s)
[INFO] Downloaded from : https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (20 kB at 18 kB/s)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] My Starter Project 1.0-SNAPSHOT .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] My Starter Project-backend ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] My Starter Project-ui 1.0-SNAPSHOT ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.739 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-18T21:39:18+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'jetty' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\hp\.m2\repository), vaadin-prereleases (https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message tells, that there is no maven Jetty plugin defined in the pom.xml where you are trying to run jetty:run target. Hence it is failing. Usually the convention in multi module maven projects is to place Jetty plugin to actual application module. In your case it is probably the "My Starter Project-ui" module. If it is not there you need to add it there.

Comment: How do i do so exactly? I dont have much experience with maven or pom files

Comment: Also doesnt this serve the same purpose?         <jetty.plugin.version>9.4.11.v20180605</jetty.plugin.version>

Comment: In your pom.xml there should be section <plugins>...</plugins> and there you need to have something like the following:   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version> ${jetty.plugin.version}</version>
   </plugin>

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When creating a debug configuration in the field goal

do not type: jetty:run

instead type: spring-boot:run